# When I move the character's body, the movement is like an alien

Tags: bones

When I click on a character's body and move it, the movement is like an alien.
When I click the bones and move it, the movement is normal. 
Why thus happen? give me an advice please.

You can understand If you watch my video. (https://www.youtube.com/embed/3sXA8kPZ970)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The character is rigged. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/rigging/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this model is rigged. control by using pose mode and moving the bones, they control the limbs.
some bones may point the elbows, hopefully, IK is set up, where you move a bone and the limb bends instead of you having to rotate
just control with the little gray knobs for that foot
each one corresponds to a moveable limb and/or joint
thank Aoradon for https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/rigging/index.html